# Share image from SD Card

Tags: android, image, share, android-sdcard

I'm trying for 2 weeks to find how to share images which are stored on an SD card with no success.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018363/android-share-bitmap-not-saved-to-sd) doesn't work to me, nor is it what I'm looking for.

I'm working with *Cam Preview app* that stores images to SD and then display them in in-app gallery:

```
   public class GalleryView extends Activity {  

   private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

private String selectedImagePath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery_view);

    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, ReadSDCard()));


    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });
}

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, selectedImagePath);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image"));
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();       
}

private List<String> ReadSDCard() {

    createDirIfNotExists();

    List<String> tFileList = new ArrayList<String>();

    //It have to be matched with the directory in SDCard
    File f = new File("/sdcard/Cam App");

    File[] files=f.listFiles();

    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        File file = files[i];
        /*It's assumed that all file in the path are in supported type*/
        tFileList.add(file.getPath());
    }

    return tFileList;
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView i;
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> FileList;
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewHolder holder;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, List<String> fList) {
        mContext = c;
        FileList = fList;
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return FileList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    } 

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FileList.get(position).toString());
        i.setImageBitmap(bm);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.i = ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagenGallery));

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder.i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        holder.i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return i;
    }
}

public TypedArray obtainStyledAttributes(int theme) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

The gallery works fine, but I don't get how to share the images saved on the SD.

How to access that images in *Cam App folder* and share the image that appears in that moment in the gallery?

I tried to use positions, but it only works with constant images. Any help/tips would be appreciated.

Comment: 05-30 18:51:11.515: E/AndroidRuntime(16500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.nightinart.camapp/com.nightinart.camapp.GalleryView}: java.lang.NullPointerException.                             This is my last log :(

Comment: I've tried this now:   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
             Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
             selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I finally found a solution to this, but it's not exactly what I want:

```
g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + "/sdcard/Cam App"), "image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select image to share:"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            //OI FILE Manager
            filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

            //MEDIA GALLERY
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            //NOW WE HAVE OUR WANTED STRING
            if(selectedImagePath!=null)
                System.out.println("selectedImagePath is the right one for you!");
            else
                System.out.println("filemanagerstring is the right one for you!");

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, selectedImageUri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image via:"));
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null) {
        //HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
        //THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    else return null;
}
```

If somebody has any better solution, please share.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine, **If you know the path of that image**

```
Intent shareit=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareit.setType("image/jpeg");
File f = new File("imagepath");
shareit.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareit, "Share Image Via"));
```

Create the file with image file name,

`File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "image_file.jpg");`