# Sharing image from android app

Tags: java, android, image, android-sharing

I am trying to share an image from my Android app. I am trying to send it as an Email attachment as well as a photo on WhatsApp.

The code is:

```
String imageUrl = Path to image (eg. sdcard/pictures/image1.jpg);
shareImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Uri uriToImage= Uri.parse(imageUrl);
                    Log.d("Image", ""+uriToImage);
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
                    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image:"));
                }
            });
```

What's happening is:

1. On WhatsApp I can share the image easily.
2. On Gmail, it says that the attachment could not be sent.
3. On Hangouts I get a toast which says `Photo couldn't be found`
4. On Facebook too, the post is not accompanied with the Image but I can post.
5. On Facebook Messenger, it crashes without opening.

The tutorial that I have followed for this is given [here](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html). The `send binary content` part of the tutorial is the one that I have implemented.

Another thing I tried was to set the image in an `ImageView` and see if it is displayed. The image is displayed correctly. Also, the log message prints the correct path of the image.

I also read and tried the answers to: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795630/share-image-from-sd-card) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018363/android-share-bitmap-not-saved-to-sd) but to no avail.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use a real MIME type. `image/*` is not a real MIME type. If your image is JPEG, use `image/jpeg`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Tried that too. Does not work.

Comment: What is the actual value of `imageUrl`? What you have embedded in your faux code listing is not a valid `Uri`. What does your `Log.d()` statement actually log?

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay. The log message is: `/storage/emulated/0/app_pictures/2/back.jpg`

Is this the incorrect Uri? If so, why?

Comment: It has no scheme. It has a duplicate slash.

Comment: @CommonsWare what does a correct `Uri` look like?

Comment: For a file, it would have the `file` scheme. As Mayur suggests, use `fromFile()` to create a proper `Uri` from a `File` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this,

```
try
                {
                    File myFile = new File(share_image_path);
                    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                    String ext = myFile.getName().substring(myFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
                    sharingIntent.setType(type);
                    sharingIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", Uri.fromFile(myFile));
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the @CommonsWare Answer is correct you missed the Schema in your Intent.putExtra() and that's why it is failing to read your image in other social media platform 
Here's my solution

```
 Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath));

 //No need to do mimeType work or ext 

 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
 intent.setType("image/*");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image:"));
```

BTW it works on all the mentioned platform

```
   Uri image_uri = Uri.parse("file://"+imagePath);
```

Another method of creating Uri and passing it to intent