# Sharing image from `RecyclerView`

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sharing

First of all, I'm sorry for my english, but I need your help.
I got a recyclerView gallery with photos and option to show the selected photo in another activity. 
I`m trying to share an image that activity to somewhere, e.g. email, but I receive an empty message with no image. 
Could you help me to find out, what am I doing wrong?

Below is the code of gallery activity and single image activity.

Thank you for answers.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GalleryAdapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    ArrayList<ImageModel> data = new ArrayList<>();


    public static String getURLForResource(int resourceId) {
        return Uri.parse("android.resource://" + R.class.getPackage().getName() + "/" + resourceId).toString();
    }

    public static String IMGS[];

    public static String MAYF[] = {
            "file:///android_asset/mayf1.jpg",
            "file:///android_asset/mayf2.gif",
            "file:///android_asset/mayf3.jpg",
            "file:///android_asset/mayf4.jpg",
            "file:///android_asset/mayf5.gif",
            "file:///android_asset/mayf6.gif",
            "file:///android_asset/mayf7.jpg",
            "file:///android_asset/mayf8.jpg",
            "file:///android_asset/mayf9.jpg",
            "file:///android_asset/mayf10.jpg"

    };

    public static String APRF[] = {
            "file:///android_asset/apr1.jpg",
            "file:///android_asset/apr2.gif",
            "file:///android_asset/apr3.jpg",
            "file:///android_asset/apr4.jpg",
            "file:///android_asset/apr5.gif",
            "file:///android_asset/apr6.gif",
            "file:///android_asset/apr7.jpg",
            "file:///android_asset/apr8.jpg",
            "file:///android_asset/apr9.jpg",
            "file:///android_asset/apr10.jpg"

    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (StartingActivity.count == 1)
            IMGS = Arrays.copyOf(APRF, APRF.length);
        else if (StartingActivity.count == 2) {
            IMGS = Arrays.copyOf(MAYF, MAYF.length);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "not filled yet",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < IMGS.length; i++) {
            ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
            imageModel.setName("Image " + i);
            imageModel.setUrl(IMGS[i]);
            data.add(imageModel);
        }


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(MainActivity.this, data);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this,
                new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data", data);
                        intent.putExtra("pos", position);
                        intent.putExtra("superUri", IMGS[position]);

                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }));


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        StartingActivity.count = 0;
    }
}
```

This part is a part of a single image.

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    public ArrayList<ImageModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int pos;
    String shPos;

    Toolbar toolbar;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        //toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
       // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        data = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("data");
        pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 0);
        shPos = getIntent().getStringExtra("superUri");

        setTitle("Открытки");

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), data);
        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                //setTitle(data.get(position).getName());

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);


        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider


        // Return true to display menu
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onShClick(MenuItem item) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(shPos));
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ArrayList<ImageModel> data = new ArrayList<>();

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<ImageModel> data) {
            super(fm);
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position, data.get(position).getName(), data.get(position).getUri());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return data.get(position).getName();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */

        String name, url;
        int pos;
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        private static final String ARG_IMG_TITLE = "image_title";
        private static final String ARG_IMG_URL = "image_url";

        @Override
        public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
            super.setArguments(args);
            this.pos = args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            this.name = args.getString(ARG_IMG_TITLE);
            this.url = args.getString(ARG_IMG_URL);
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber, String name, String url) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            args.putString(ARG_IMG_TITLE, name);
            args.putString(ARG_IMG_URL, url);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_image);

            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(url).thumbnail(0.1f).into(imageView);

            return rootView;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is an example of trying to share image via gmail. I can see the image "attached", but can`t open it. Another email receives an empty message with no attachment inside.
[sharing example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZHIK.png)

Comment: wats the error ??

Comment: no error, it just sends nothing

Comment: Are you trying to share via facebook? Some apps restrict sharing and you'll have to implement their special sharing protocols. Try WhatsApp.

Comment: I tried bluetooth, telegram ang gmail.

Comment: Is the image being loaded into imageView successfully?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29629335/5841416, This thread might be helpful.

Comment: I`ve added a screenshot from tablet pc that may help to describe the problem. Image loads into imageView correctly.

Comment: The solution from thread above also returns the same problem